# More informations about the TPtCC() signature

Tags: xades4j

I am working on SignerTTest.java with "SignerTestBase" :

```
    public class SignerTestBase extends SignatureServicesTestBase
{
    /**/
    static protected KeyingDataProvider keyingProviderMy;
    static protected KeyingDataProvider keyingProviderNist;

    static
{
    try
    {
        keyingProviderMy = createFileSystemKeyingDataProvider("pkcs12", "my/LG.pfx", "mykeypass", true);
        keyingProviderNist = createFileSystemKeyingDataProvider("pkcs12", "csrc.nist/test4.p12", "password", false);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("SignerTestBase init failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static Document getTestDocument() throws Exception
{
    //return getDocument("document.xml");

    //==that I changed=====================================================================
    return getDocument("fv.xml");


}
```

I have the class SignerTTest.java

```
@Test
public void testSignTPtCC() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("signTPtCitizenCard");

    if (!onWindowsPlatform())
        fail("Test written for the Windows platform");

    Document doc = getTestDocument();
    Element elemToSign = doc.getDocumentElement();
    try
    {
        PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider ptccKeyingDataProv = new PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(
                //"C:\\Windows\\System32\\pteidpkcs11.dll", "PT_CC",
                "C:\\Windows\\system32\\pteidpkcs11.dll", "PT_CC",


                new FirstCertificateSelector(), null, null, false);

        SignerT signer = (SignerT)new XadesTSigningProfile(ptccKeyingDataProv).withAlgorithmsProvider(PtCcAlgorithmsProvider.class).newSigner();
        new xades4j.production.Enveloped(signer).sign(elemToSign);

        outputDocument(doc, "document.signed.t.bes.ptcc.xml");
    } catch (ProviderException ex)
    {
        fail(" !!!!!!!PT CC PKCS#11 provider not configured !!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

And in my main.class :

```
 System.out.println("============================================================================");          
        System.out.println("XADESTEST : T SIGNATURE");
        System.out.println("============================================================================");
        System.out.println();

        SignerTTest signerTTest = new SignerTTest();
        System.out.println("signerTTest : " + signerTTest.toString()); 

        /**
         *    ==== NOT OK =====
         */
        signerTTest.testSignTPtCC();
```

And in my console I get :

```
> ============================================================================
XADESTEST : T SIGNATURE
============================================================================

signerTTest : xadestest.SignerTTest@1304043
signTPtCitizenCard
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError:  !!!!!!!PT CC PKCS#11 provider not configured !!!!!!!!!!!!
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:58)
    at xadestest.SignerTTest.testSignTPtCC(SignerTTest.java:119)
    at xadestest.XadesTest.main(XadesTest.java:117)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Please may you advice me on the problem during I am searching ?

thanks,

Will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That test is written to use the Portuguese Citizen Card PKCS#11 provider. As the exception message states, you don't have the provider installed. If you need to test the lib with a PKCS#11 provider, change the configuration to use its native lib instead.

P.S.: the lib docs and examples are pretty clear on this..please take a better look. also, please vote the answers here.